# What do locals call San Francisco?

Tags: local-customs, san-francisco, local-knowledge

I heard that San Franciscans hate nicknames like "*San Fran*" or "*Frisco*". If I want to travel around San Francisco without sounding like a rube, what should I call it?

Comment: Truckers will refer to it as 'shakey-town'. I called it 'Frisco' for a while, but reverted to the full 'San Francisco'.  I promise that nobody will think you're a rube for saying 'San Francisco', but they might if you throw out an anachronism or naive malaprop!

Comment: @GayotFow I believe Los Angeles is more often called "Shakey Town" (but I have never heard a local refer to either Los Angeles or San Francisco that way).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany thanks for the heads' up; I'm happy to call LA, "L.A." or "lahlah", on occasion the full 'Los Angeles'

Comment: @Azor-Ahai I actually lived in a town called Frisco, in Colorado. People kept assuming I was talking about San Francisco :/

Comment: Yes, it's pretentious and really annoying but locals do simply say "I'm from the city."

Comment: I lived in Silicon Valley and Southern California.  In and around San Francisco, it is called "The City".  Even people in San Jose call it "The City".  The other term is "San Francisco".  The people of Southern California, famous for shortening city names, call it "Frisco".  I rarely hear "SanFran" or "SF".  Sometimes I hear "SFX".  I do believe the locals frown on people who call their city "Frisco".

Comment: @SpehroPefhany:  The Southern California folks call "Los Angeles" "El Ay", or the letters L.A.  Too many syllables to call it by its real name.  Many city, county and region names are shortened by the locals.  Examples:  Orange County - "OC"; Rancho Santa Margarita - RSM; Inland Empire - "IE".

Comment: I have always found it a bit odd that nobody ever shortens it to "Cisco" ...

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yes, that's what I called it when I was there back in the 1980s, though more usually it was "Pico" (Rivera) or "El Monte" or whatever suburb. If you didn't know a fair number of the city names you'd not know in which direction to get onto the freeway in that pre-GPS era.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Who calls the Inland Empire "IE"? I live in SoCal, and I've never heard IE used as an acronym for anything but the browser. (I've also never heard anyone call SF "SFX", but do occasionally hear people call it SF - I *often* see it *written* as SF, but speaking it out loud is much rarer.)

Comment: News channels often call it the IE, both TV and radio.  Usually if they mention the OC, they'll talk about the IE.

Comment: As a sidenote, "San Franciscoans" is not a thing. You can use "San Franciscans" instead.

Comment: Alot of us in southern central California will call it SF or SanFran on occasion. There's the perennial favorite "Sahfrasisco". However, unless for some reason we need to be that specific, usually we'll just say we are headed to "The Bay".

Comment: Just say San Francisco. No need to say anything else. Yes I live here.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Most locals just call it ***the City***, when it's clear from context that you are talking about the local area.  You could say: "I'm staying at a nice hotel in the City".  This will be understood to mean "within the San Francisco city limits." (Incidentally, this is a [smaller region](https://www.google.com/maps/place/San+Francisco,+CA/@37.6637037,-122.5951879,10z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x80859a6d00690021:0x4a501367f076adff) than most outsiders might guess).  In writing, capitalization is optional.

Otherwise, simply call it "San Francisco".  There isn't a shorter nickname in common use.  It is a lot of syllables; locals tend to say it fast and slur a bit, something like "Sanfruh sisko".

Spanish speakers should note that, as with most Spanish place-names in California, most English-speaking locals use a semi-anglicized pronunciation.  "San" is rhymed with "ban", "man", "tan".  "Francisco" sounds like the English name "Francis" plus "ko", but the accent is still on "cis".  The vowel in "Fran" is either the same vowel as "San", or else an unstressed "schwa" vowel.

"SF" is acceptable in writing (especially headlines, text messages, etc), but not so common in conversation.  "SFO" refers to the [airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Francisco_International_Airport) but not the city.  I personally have never heard or seen "SFX".

"San Fran" and "Frisco" are deprecated and will tend to mark you as an outsider.  Locals tend to find "Frisco" particularly annoying, and (allegedly) [have  felt this way since 1872](http://www.emperorsbridge.org/blog/2016/2/12/on-the-trail-of-the-elusive-frisco-proclamation).

(I think there's a convention that people who work in the airline industry are "allowed" to say "SanFran".  So the agent at the airport ticket counter might tell you "Your bags are checked through to SanFran", but don't take that as an indication of general practice.)

---

If you want to refer to the greater metropolitan area (including Oakland, San Jose, etc), and not just the city proper, it's "the Bay Area".

This is further subdivided into "North Bay" (north of the Bay itself, e.g. Marin, Sonoma, Napa and Solano Counties), "East Bay" (Oakland, Berkeley, and the rest of Alameda and Contra Costa Counties), and "South Bay" (San Jose and its immediate suburbs).  There is no "West Bay". The ill-defined region between San Francisco and the South Bay (including South San Francisco, San Bruno, etc) is "the Peninsula".

As a side note, I don't think locals use the term "Silicon Valley" much; they're more likely to refer to specific cities like Palo Alto, Santa Clara, etc.

(Source: born and raised in the North Bay, and visit frequently.  If there are emerging trends that differ from this, suggestions are welcome!)

Comment: So `San Fran` and `Frisco` are no-nos like I heard?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai: Yes, they will tend to mark you as a tourist.  As a special exception, I believe "SanFran" is considered acceptable to say if you work for an airline.

Comment: What is the sentence for incorrect use? Do they throw you in a locally sourced artisan jail?

Comment: @Gusdor They pommel you into unconsciousness with an organic carrot.

Comment: I love how those tiny corners of Angel Island and Alameda Island are within the city limits.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: After zooming out some more, TIL that the Farallones are too.

Comment: I have heard that using SF in conversation can flag you as someone from Southern California (and indeed, when I was at UC Irvine people often used it).

Comment: @fkraiem - Guilty. It just follows naturally from growing up with "LA".

Comment: If you want to be formal, you can call it "The City and County of San Francisco".

Answer (score 31):

The [natives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indigenous_peoples_of_California) called the San Francisco Bay area <s>Ramaytush</s> [**Awaste**](http://articles.latimes.com/1985-01-01/local/me-10267_1_tribes).

Comment: That may be correct, but using that name will either (1) make you not be understood, of (2) sound like a criticism to the residents of San Francisco. Unless the aim of the sentence is to insult them, using that name should thus probably be avoided.

Comment: I always love a pedant when I see one! Oh wait, I can't **see** you, so no...

Comment: The natives of California are the indigenous people of that area. Are we just going to erase their history from memory and replace them with the current "natives"?

Comment: Your citation doesn't support your claim.  It says that Ramaytush is the name of the language spoken by the indigenous people of the area, not that this is their name for the city itself (or even the area it's located on).

Comment: @Frisbetarian: "going to"?

Comment: **This answer correctly refers to the natives.** Once can only assume that the OP meant "locals" and even only in the stricter sense "European and Asian derived locals".

Comment: Everyone who originates from San Francisco is a native. Those who argue for narrower definitions are the kind responsible for a lot of bloodshed throughout history.

Comment: Let's consult [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/native): **native**, *n.*.  1. one born or reared in a particular place.  2. (a) an original or indigenous inhabitant (b)  something indigenous to a particular locality. 3. a local resident; especially :  a person who has always lived in a place as distinguished from a visitor or a temporary resident.  I interpreted the question to be using the word in senses 1 and/or 3.

Comment: As you may know we generally discourage link only answers, consider expanding a little and adding relevant info from that link into your answer

Comment: I appreciate the tongue-in-cheek response, but I was referring to San Francisco natives (of any race, I see no reason to limit the scope to European and Asian locals), not Indigenous peoples. As others have pointed out, you're not even correct, as a cursory Wikipedia search turns up `awaste`, not `Ramaytush`

Comment: Nothing ironic in my response. You asked what the natives call the area and I provided an answer. Whether you want to cram race into the issue is your prerogative.

Comment: I doubt their are any natives still alive that call it awaste.

Comment: @NateEldredge so did frisbetarian. he's just being "funny" (apparently being pedantic on the internet is funny).

Comment: I don't believe OP specified he's in possession of a time machine...

Answer (score 8):

I was born and raised in the San Francisco Bay Area and usually people just refer to San Francisco as *San Francisco*. I lived in the East Bay Area, and someone would say something like *Let's go get dinner in the City* and this would mean that you are going to San Francisco. However, I feel that it would be better to say *San Francisco* when you are in San Francisco as saying *the City*, at least in my perception of it, is referring to San Francisco when elsewhere in the *Bay Area*.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a very much opinion-based question and experiences will vary greatly from person to person, even amongst locals -- so take all these answers with a grain of salt.

I was born and raised in San Francisco proper, and I personally like to use SF in both speech and text a lot because it is short and simple.  I think most of my friends do the same.

If your goal is to try to pretend to be a local, I suppose some of these answers may help you.  However, if you're just trying to be more likeable to the locals, I'd like to point out that most people don't really care what you call the city.  SF is a diverse city and many people don't speak English well enough to care about a detail like this.  (I grew up in an immigrant family and we really don't care.)  Even among proficient English speakers, the ones that do care are a minority (and these are the people you probably want to avoid anyway).

Answer (score 2):

I was born and raised in San Francisco, and I use SF a lot, mostly in writing, but in speech, too. "San Francisco" is long to write out, so you'll often write "SF." Locals also say "San Francisco," but that's a pretty long name to say as well.

"SF" is pretty ingrained in our lexicon - the baseball team is called the "SF Giants," and the football team is called the "SF 49ers."

Only tourists, newcomers, or people outside the Bay Area call it "San Fran" or "Frisco." That makes San Franciscans cringe.

It's really odd that people living in a major city or region are LESS likely to give it catchy nicknames. I remember, for a time in the 90s-2000s, "SoCal" was used a lot. Now I hear it a lot less. People from that area tend to say they're from "Southern California" if they don't want to be more specific. But chances are, especially, if they're non-white, they're from the LA area.

Lately I've been hearing "The Bay" used to refer to the Bay Area. I've never heard of a shortened way of saying The Bay Area before. I used to think this was some outsiders' way of saying it - like how they say San Fran or Frisco - but I'm hearing Bay Area people say "The Bay," too. Maybe I'm just not that used to it, but it sounds bad to me.

"The City" seemed like it was used more in the 90s-2000s--at least, with the capitalized T and C, in writing or in speech. Now, when people say "the city," I think they're just referring to the city in general, the way you would refer to any major city in a metropolitan area. I've always thought "The City" was very pretentious. Why is SF "The City?" There are many important cities in the Bay Area, and SF isn't necessarily any better.

Answer (score -3):

in some circles, the term 'tai fao' is still in use - it means 'big town' or 'city' in chinese.  some non-chinese use this term, but it's probably not widespread.  still good to know.

and btw, only a real hobo can legitimately call the city 'frisco' - and they are becoming thinner on the ground...

Comment: How wide spread is this use, only Chinese speakers or is it in general use by a bigger group?