# Is there any way around going to San Francisco to get a German visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, germany

I need a German visa. I am on a student visa in Seattle. I am an Indian Citizen so  I definitely need a visa to enter and I don't want to go down to San Francisco to get a visa, any suggestions what I should do?

Comment: Yes, go to a different Schengen country. Or at least pretend to.

Comment: You could also fly to Oakland if it's SFO you're objecting to. At least it's in the same time zone.

Comment: You may be interested in this question of mine while you're there: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61570/what-do-locals-call-san-francisco :)

Comment: @Azor-Ahai I suggest that Karan is trying to avoid making a 1,600mi (2,500km) round trip, not objecting to any specific Bay-Area airport! (I.e., "SFO" is being used as an abbreviation for San Francisco, not for its airport.)

Comment: Can you clarify why going to San Francisco (or perhaps the SFO airport in particular) is a problem? Do you dislike trolley cars? Or you just don't want to trave *at all*? Knowing your reason will help us know what kind of alternative you're looking for.

Comment: Can you get to Canda and apply in Vancouver?

Comment: @Flimzy I think the most sensible assumption here is simply that the OP doesn't want to make a 1000km journey just to get a visa

Comment: @Aganju doesn't work, updated my answer below

Comment: @blackbird57: I agree that's the most reasonable *assumption*. But not having to make an assumption would be better.

Comment: Yes, i am student on tight budget, i have saved up for this trip already through many jobs and now going and coming back to the Bay area adds up to my total cost. thanks anyways for all the inputs, looks like i will anyways have to go down to get one.

Answer (score 11):

**Unfortunately, you cannot.**

According to their [consulates](http://www.germany.info/Vertretung/usa/en/03__Consulates/00/__Consulates.html) page the San Francisco mission covers Washington state where you are, if you are in the catchment area you cannot apply elsewhere. It does seem to be the closest to you anyway.

Also, you have to travel there in person because they now collect [biometric data](http://www.germany.info/Vertretung/usa/en/05__Legal/02__Directory__Services/01__Visa/__Visa.html) (meaning you can't mail-in an application)

> Now, starting Thursday, May 15, 2014, the visa sections at the German
>   missions in the U.S. will begin collecting biometric data, that is,
>   fingerprints, for Schengen visas as part of the Visa Information
>   System (VIS).

**Alternatives**

If you're looking for alternatives, you **cannot** apply at the Vancouver office because they specifically only serve [Canadians](http://www.kanada.diplo.de/Vertretung/kanada/en/02/visa/__visa.html) or Canadian PR holders, and BC residents have to apply at the Swiss office anyway.

> Only applications from residents of Canada (Permanent residents,
>   persons holding a Canadian student visa or work permit) can be
>   accepted. Applications from persons holding long-term visitor’s visa
>   can only be accepted, if you can prove that it was not possible to
>   apply in your home country.

Similarly, the Swedish consulate in Seattle is an [honorary consulate](http://www.consulateofswedenseattle.com/?page_id=325) and will advise you to apply in San Francisco with the Norwegians or in DC at the embassy.

San Francisco is also the application office for the [French](http://www.ambafrance-us.org/spip.php?article330) and [Norwegian](http://www.norway.org/embassy/) embassies. I'm mentioning this because they have chapters in Seattle. I couldn't find any other Schengen country with a visa service in Seattle

Comment: The good news, at least, is that there are frequent and relatively inexpensive flights between Seattle and San Francisco.  Just think if you lived in rural Montana!

Comment: Actually, Canadian citizens who are not resident in Canada may not apply in Vancouver. Also, contrary to your text, but as noted in the quote, the consulate also serves non-permanent residents. The rule is that you must apply at the consulate in whose area you live.  A person resident in Ottawa can't apply in Vancouver either, regardless of citizenship. (There are exceptions for people who have a compelling reason to apply elsewhere than the "home" consulate, but they do not apply here.)

Comment: @phoog yea ok I didn't quote the whole text only the parts relevant to the OP

Answer (score 0):

If it is a special hardship for you to go to San Francisco *and not another German consulate in the United Stated,* you might be able to get your application processed e.g. by the consulate in Boston or Miami. This is an even longer trip, but you might be in one of those places, anyway.